# Need to find exact match and replace using regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a input where i need to replace the `&&` with  **and**

**Note :** The **&&** as left and right the spaces and output should also contain spaces left and right with **and**

**Input :**

```
s = 'n && && && && && &&n'
```

**My code :**

```
m=re.sub(r'\s[&&]\s', ' and ',s)
print(m)
```

**My output :**

```
n && && && && && &&n
```

**Expected output :**

```
n and and and and and &&n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want lookbehind and lookahead expressions for the spaces so that the matches do not overlap because `re.sub()` will "return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of `pattern` in `string` by the replacement `repl`".

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for explanation of these expressions.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'n && && && && && &&n'
>>> m = re.sub(r'(?<=\s)&&(?=\s)', 'and', s)
>>> print(m)
n and and and and and &&n
```

If you want to capture `&&` at the end or beginning of the string, then use `\S` as suggested by @tim-biegeleisen nearby.

Comment: Your answer is fine so long as `&&` at the beginning or end is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

I would do a regex replacement on `(?<!\S)&&(?!\S)`:

```py
import re

s = 'n && && && && && &&n'
output = re.sub(r'(?<!\S)&&(?!\S)', 'and', s)
print(output)  # n and and and and and &&n
```

The regex pattern here says to match:

- `(?<!\S)` assert that what precedes is whitespace OR start of the input
- `&&` match literal `&&`
- `(?!\S)` assert that what follows is whitespace OR end of the input

Answer (score 1):

You can match just && and then *assert* `\s` to the right instead of matching it.

The notation `[&&]` is a character class, which is the same as `[&]` or just `&`

```
\s&&(?=\s)
```

**Explanation**

- `\s` Match a whitespace char
- `&&` Match literally
- `(?=\s)` Positive lookahead, assert `\s` directly to the right of the current position

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BloZ5W/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/vjFkuf)

```
import re

s = 'n && && && && && &&n'
m = re.sub(r'\s&&(?=\s)', ' and', s)
print(m)
```

Output

```
n and and and and and &&n
```

Comment: Meaning please : `\s&&(?=\s)`

Comment: @memotib827 I have added an explanation of the regex to the answer.

Comment: @bobblebubble Hi there, that color was changed automatically I think...looks good on me right? It matches the bird :-) That space at the end should not be there of course, thanks!

Comment: @Thefourthbird It looks fresh spring color, yes and a bit variety is good anyways... wondered if there is another 4th bird but there can be *only one* of course. :)